# Initialise specific complication without user input - android wear api

Tags: java, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-2.0

I want to be able to read data from a complication, like the weather or steps count, without having to create a complication for the user to select which complication to show in the watch face.

Is it possible to initialise a specific complication, like the weather or steps, without the input of the user?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but you are limited to the system providers, or your custom
complication providers.

Custom provider as default:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/watchface/WatchFaceService.Engine#setDefaultComplicationProvider(int,%20android.content.ComponentName,%20int)

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-providers/exposing-data-complications#provider-specified-safe-watch-faces

System providers as default:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/watchface/WatchFaceService.Engine#setDefaultSystemComplicationProvider(int,%20int,%20int)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/complications/SystemProviders